# Android command line for selecting menu items

Tags: android, command-line, adb

I have an activity comprising menu of five items. I want to click on one of them using command line.
I can open the activity via "am start" command and then open the menu using the keyevent.
But after that i am not able to find a way to select an item from it.

Answer (score 1):

If the desired menu entry has focus then

```
adb shell /system/bin/sh /system/bin/input keyevent 23
```

or just

```
adb shell /system/bin/input keyevent 23
```

should work.

That is [KeyEvent#KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/view/KeyEvent.java#KeyEvent.0KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER), other key numbers in that link as well.